# Can i get the generated ip-address or domain name of flask_ngrok or py-ngrok and return it to 127.0.0.1/

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, ngrok, pyngrok

I'm trying to get the generated domain name or IP-address of flask_ngrok or py-ngrok after been deploy. I want to deploy flask_app to localhost and get the new IP-address or domain name on the main page.

> I.E:  If I access **127.0.0.1/** I want it to return something like
> **You can now log in through https://aaf8447ee878.ngrok.io/**

I have tried checking through the directories and read some help but I can't still get it. Thanks in  advance ❤

Comment: Have a look at Flask's [Request context](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/reqcontext/), then have a look at `request.host`. Is that what you're looking for? If the request is from `localhost` or `127`, render a different page.

Answer (score 2):

add

```
import atexit
import json
import os
import platform
import shutil
import subprocess
import tempfile
import time
import zipfile
from pathlib import Path
from threading import Timer

import requests


def _run_ngrok():
    ngrok_path = str(Path(tempfile.gettempdir(), "ngrok"))
    _download_ngrok(ngrok_path)
    system = platform.system()
    if system == "Darwin":
        command = "ngrok"
    elif system == "Windows":
        command = "ngrok.exe"
    elif system == "Linux":
        command = "ngrok"
    else:
        raise Exception(f"{system} is not supported")
    executable = str(Path(ngrok_path, command))
    os.chmod(executable, 777)

    ngrok = subprocess.Popen([executable, 'http', '5000'])
    atexit.register(ngrok.terminate)
    localhost_url = "http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels"  # Url with tunnel details
    time.sleep(1)
    tunnel_url = requests.get(localhost_url).text  # Get the tunnel information
    j = json.loads(tunnel_url)

    tunnel_url = j['tunnels'][0]['public_url']  # Do the parsing of the get
    tunnel_url = tunnel_url.replace("https", "http")
    return tunnel_url


def _download_ngrok(ngrok_path):
    if Path(ngrok_path).exists():
        return
    system = platform.system()
    if system == "Darwin":
        url = "https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-stable-darwin-amd64.zip"
    elif system == "Windows":
        url = "https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-stable-windows-amd64.zip"
    elif system == "Linux":
        url = "https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip"
    else:
        raise Exception(f"{system} is not supported")
    download_path = _download_file(url)
    with zipfile.ZipFile(download_path, "r") as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall(ngrok_path)


def _download_file(url):
    local_filename = url.split('/')[-1]
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    download_path = str(Path(tempfile.gettempdir(), local_filename))
    with open(download_path, 'wb') as f:
        shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
    return download_path

def start_ngrok():
    global ngrok_address
    ngrok_address = _run_ngrok()
    print(f" * Running on {ngrok_address}")
    print(f" * Traffic stats available on http://127.0.0.1:4040")


def run_with_ngrok(app):
    """
    The provided Flask app will be securely exposed to the public internet via ngrok when run,
    and the its ngrok address will be printed to stdout
    :param app: a Flask application object
    :return: None
    """
    old_run = app.run

    def new_run():
        thread = Timer(1, start_ngrok)
        thread.setDaemon(True)
        thread.start()
        old_run()
    app.run = new_run

####################
```

dont import flask_ngrok
at the end at before **name** == '**main**' add this function

```
def ngrok_url():
    global tunnel_url
    while True:
        try:
            print(ngrok_address)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

and after before app.run() put

```
thread = Timer(1, ngrok_url)
thread.setDaemon(True)
thread.start()
```

and run Warning: this will crash your code editor/ or terminal if u dont want that in the ngrok url function replace print with whatever you want to do with the url

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

and you dont need that

```
global tunnel_url
def ngrok_url():
    while True:
        try:
            print(ngrok_address)
        except Exception as e:
                print(e)
```

you can delete the threading part before the **name** == '**main**' too after the imports set
`ngrok_address = ''`
then you can accses the ngrok_address anywhere in your code

Answer (score 0):

I found out the easiest way to do this is the just copy the url when the user is visiting the site. You can do this by...

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    global url
    url = request.url
    # url = url.replace('http://', 'https://', 1)
    url = url.split('.ngrok.io')[0]
    url += '.ngrok.io'
```